# Simple validation of string/number behaving incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json, validation, yup

I am using `yup` to perform a simple JavaScript data validation. However I am getting unexpected behaviour. I'm sure I'm misusing their API but this is not obvious to me after reviewing their docs. I run the following unit test and it fails (I expect it to pass). Any ideas?

```
import { object, string } from 'yup';

test('validator', async () => {
  let schema = object({
    name: string(),
  });

  expect(await schema.isValid({ name: 123 })).toEqual(false);
});
```

Using version

```
"yup": "^0.32.11"
```

Attempted running this validation and within a jest unit test and it fails. Tried reviewing their API docs for other validation methods

Comment: Seems there is an options parameter that can be passed `{ strict: true }` which resolved this. I assume if this is not set the parser is trying to cast the number to a string?

https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemavalidatevalue-any-options-object-promiseinfertypeschema-validationerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected output because this is how the *yup* library has been implemented. When you apply the `strict` option to a schema the yup parser will not be run so erasing the possibility of  transforming your `number` value to a `string` value due to the [type_coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion). So with the `strict` option the `number` value `123` will be validated "as is" (no type_coercion), and because it is not a `string` value the validation will fail, without the `strict` option there will be the type coercion and the validation will be a success.